# Looping through styles with map function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to loop through styles with the map function but it returns the numbers 83 to 90 instead why does this happen?

```
let stylesArray = [styles.punt1, styles.punt2, 
                    styles.punt3, styles.punt4, 
                    styles.punt5, styles.punt6, 
                    styles.punt7, styles.punt8
                  ]

 {stylesArray.map(function(object, i){
    console.log(object);
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={openQuestionOverview} style={[styles.punt, object]}>
      <Image source={vraag1} />
    </TouchableHighlight>
 })}
```

Comment: What are `83` and `90`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the map result:

```
let stylesArray = [styles.punt1, styles.punt2, 
                   styles.punt3, styles.punt4, 
                   styles.punt5, styles.punt6, 
                   styles.punt7, styles.punt8
                  ]

 {stylesArray.map(function(object, i){
    console.log(object);
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={openQuestionOverview} style={[styles.punt, object]}>
            <Image source={vraag1} />
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )
 })}
```

You also don't use the result of the mapping step.

Comment: Thank you this works! I noticed it also gives me a warning if I don't add the prop `key={i}` TouchableHighlight